# Как сделать так, чтобы RegEx не убирал точки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно распарсить эту строку:

```
"sqlite://root:123@localhost:8080/mydatabase.db"
```

Я использую регулярные выражения. Вот паттерн, `\W+`. Но он исключает все знаки препинания, включая нужную мне точку в названии файла базы данных. Как сделать так, чтобы после последнего слеша RegEx останавливался?

Comment: Что нужно получить-то?

Comment: sqlite, root, 123, localhost, 8080, mydatabase.db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы из `\W` исключить символ точки, нужно заменить *эквивалентным исключающим символьным классом, `[^\w]`*, и добавить в него исключаемый символ.

Используйте

```
[^\w.]+
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/K9ADlF/1).

Comment: Я думаю, что ваше решение более лаконично и выберу ваш ответ, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю вам такой вариант: `([a-z0-9.]+)`
Чтобы проверить своё регулярное выражение, вы можете воспользоваться сайтом https://regex101.com/

Comment: Хороший вариант, но после парсинга строки этим выражением остаются ненужные знаки препинания

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь вы пишите на языке python

```
re.sub(r"(://|:|@|/)", " ", str).split(" ")
```